# Problem with token when unchecked "Enable signatures" and "Enable user pictures"

Tags: 7, users, tokens

How when i want unchecked "**Enable signatures**" and "**Enable user pictures**" show those errors:

```
 The Body is using the following invalid tokens: [sito: login-url].
 The Body is using the following invalid tokens: [sito: login-url].
 The Body is using the following invalid tokens: [sito: login-url].
 The Body is using the following invalid tokens: [site: url-breve].
```

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is showing up because you are using wrong names of the tokens.

1. `[sito: login-url]` should be `[site:login-url]`.
2. `[site: url-breve]` should be `[site:url]`.